# why always sync in asp.net mvc with asynchronous action（async await）

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

I want to use async in 'action',but it is sync always when I access the page with 3 tabs the same time.

I find the next tab page's 'startTime' is the previous tab 'endTime'.So it's sync not async.

thanks a lot.

```
    public class TestController : Controller
{
    public async Task<string> Index()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            List<string> lst = new List<string>();
            lst.Add(string.Format("startTime：{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
            var s = new Stopwatch();
            s.Start();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            s.Stop();
            lst.Add(string.Format("endTime：{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
            lst.Add(string.Format("total：{0}", s.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString()));
            return string.Join("<br/>", lst.ToArray());
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your might be misunderstanding what async controller methods are. It means that during a long running task, the thread is returned to the thread pool and therefore more requests can be handled (It does not reduce the time taken for the method to execute). [Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4)

Comment: but the ui thead is waiting always. until the previous request is done.

Comment: That has nothing to do with making your method async.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it has nothing to do with async/await and you are confusing it with parallel request execution.

Regarding to your question, my guess is that this occurs due to session locking.
By default ASP.NET MVC handler processes one request at the time per one session. The reason is that MVC handler assumes that on each request session could be modified and all sequential requests need to be processed with the up to date session value. You can easily change this behavior by setting correct `SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly` or `SessionStateBehavior.Disabled` on your controller:

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public async Task<string> Index()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ...
        });
    }
}
```

By applying this attribute you disable the session locking and allow multiple request to be executed in parallel on the same session object.

Comment: I try it ,it's still so. and it's a new mvc project created by vs  just now.